# Imported a group but cant edit it?

Tags: import

Im trying to import some diamonds into my scene but cant edit them.
Is it possible to import it and edit it?

Here is the [image]

[image]

Is it possible to get the diamonds and use them too?

Comment: Please describe in your question how you imported them and show screenshots of the result.

Comment: give me a sec I will get the .blend

Comment: A blend is good, but ideally blend files should be supplemental to good question content, e.g. a description of how you imported them and screenshots of the result. We ideally want people to be able to answer the question (or see if they have the same problem) as easily as possible.